# In Netty4,why read and write both in OutboundHandler

Tags: netty

I have a question in Netty4,  An I/O event is handled by either a `ChannelInboundHandler` or a `ChannelOutboundHandler`

1. The first question is why read and write method both in `ChannelOutboundHandler`?
2. why trigger `read()` method in the `fireChannelReadComplete()`? What is the design philosophy?

```java
@Override
public ChannelPipeline fireChannelReadComplete() {
    head.fireChannelReadComplete();
    if (channel.config().isAutoRead()) {
        read();
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Inbound handlers are supposed to handle inbound events.  Events are triggered by external stimuli such as data received from a socket.

Outbound handlers are supposed to intercept the operations issued by your application.

Re: Q1) `read()` is an operation you can issue to tell Netty to continue reading the inbound data from the socket, and that's why it's in an outbound handler.

Re: Q2) You don't usually issue a `read()` operation because Netty does that for you automatically if `autoRead` property is set to `true`.  Typical flow when `autoRead` is on:

1. Netty triggers an inbound event `channelActive` when socket is connected, and then issues a `read()` request to itself (see `DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive()`)
2. Netty reads something from the socket in response to the `read()` request.
3. If something was read, Netty triggers `channelRead()`.
4. If there's nothing left to read, Netty triggers `channelReadComplete()`
5. Netty issues another `read()` request to continue reading from the socket.

If `autoRead` is off, you have to issue a `read()` request manually.  It's sometimes useful to turn `autoRead` off.  For example, you might want to implement a backpressure mechanism by keeping the received data in the kernel space.

Comment: This reasoning is not convincing. Inbound & Outbound are generally defined based on the direction of data flow, not based on the direction of who is calling whom. It looks to me like a bad design

Comment: Why would you ask a channel outbound handler for reading? Completely counter intuitive/also known as bad design